# How can I get past this C4430 Compiler Error in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm extremely new to the coding scene and, even more so to coding with C++.  I'm currently building a side program for my class as it was strongly recommended, but I can't seem to get it to compile.  I keep getting a C4430 error (missing type specifier - int assumed).  I'm not seeing anything like this in my reading material either, so I figured I'd reach out here for help as a second set of eyes is always a good idea.  If it matters, I am coding this with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition.  I'm still learning, but I'm also used to coding in Java at this point so I'm at a loss.

The program itself is a program I have written in Java, that I have adapted for use in C++.  It's a very basic salary calculation program that spits out weekly, monthly, and annual wages while also accounting for Taxes.  Initially, it had included the scanner utility in Java, but I haven't seen anything like that in C++ yet.  Ideally, it would spit this information out without a problem.
  I have tried adding `return 0;` to the end of my code, but I am still getting the C4430.  I have also reclassed my `main` as `double` instead of `int`, to no avail.

I have included my code, below:

```
#include <iostream>
double salaryCalculator; main ()
{
double hourlyWage = 15.00;
int hoursWorkedWeek = 40;
double weeklyWage = 0.0;
double monthlyWage = 0.0;
double annualWage = 0.0;
double overtimeHours = 3.0;
double overtimeMulti = 1.5;
double overtimeHourlyWage = 0.0;
double overtimeTotalWage = 0.0;

overtimeHourlyWage = hourlyWage * overtimeMulti;
overtimeTotalWage = overtimeHourlyWage * overtimeHours;
std::cout << "You have /n" << overtimeHours << "hours of overtime at a rate of " << overtimeHourlyWage << "an hour, for a total of " << overtimeTotalWage;

weeklyWage = overtimeTotalWage + (hoursWorkedWeek * hourlyWage);
std::cout << "Your weekly wage is: /n" << weeklyWage;

monthlyWage = weeklyWage * 4;
std::cout << "Your monthly wage is: /n" << monthlyWage;

annualWage = weeklyWage * 52;
std::cout << "Your annual wage before taxes is: /n" << annualWage;

enum class TaxDeductions;
{
};
        double incomeTax = 0.11;
        double stateTax = 0.04;
        double socialSecurityTax = 0.062;
        double medicareTax = 0.0145;

        double firstWTax = weeklyWage * incomeTax;
        double secondWTax = weeklyWage * stateTax;
        double thirdWTax = weeklyWage * socialSecurityTax;
        double fourthWTax = weeklyWage * medicareTax;
        double weeklyTax = firstWTax + secondWTax + thirdWTax + fourthWTax;

        double firstMTax = monthlyWage * incomeTax;
        double secondMTax = monthlyWage * stateTax;
        double thirdMTax = monthlyWage * socialSecurityTax;
        double fourthMTax = monthlyWage * medicareTax;
        double monthlyTax = firstMTax + secondMTax + thirdMTax + fourthMTax;

        double firstATax = annualWage * incomeTax;
        double secondATax = annualWage * stateTax;
        double thirdATax = annualWage * socialSecurityTax;
        double fourthATax = annualWage * medicareTax;
        double annualTax = firstATax + secondATax + thirdATax + fourthATax;



        double weeklyTakeHome = weeklyWage - weeklyTax;
        double monthlyTakehome = monthlyWage - monthlyTax;
        double annualTakeHome = annualWage - annualTax;

        std::cout << "Your weekly total take home is /n" << weeklyTakeHome;
        std::cout << "Your monthly total take home is: /n" << monthlyTakehome;
        std::cout << "Your annual total take home is /n" << annualTakeHome;

        return 0;
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should main() return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c)

Comment: If you are new to C++, why do you write so much code at a time before testing if it works as you intend?

Comment: The link helps me explain why I am getting and answers my question, as well as a treasure trove of information I'll probably need.  Thank you for the help!

The reason for so much code before testing is that I got a little overzealous with adapting my program to a new coding language and did not think to test as I progressed, a habit I intend to break.  Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to specify the return type for the entry point main ()!

Add int before main

```
#include <iostream>


double salaryCalculator;


int main() {
    //code body..
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I got it, I think.  So the primary point here, if I'm understanding correctly, is that I need to define the return type in C++ as I would in Java.  I'm not sure how I didn't think of this sooner, thank you for the feedback and help in understanding.

Comment: @SteveP.  you're welcome

Answer (score 3):

If you remove the function's body for a moment, you'll see this:

```
double salaryCalculator; main ()
{
}
```

Or, with better formatting:

```
double salaryCalculator;  // variable declaration

main () // function definition
{
}
```

But you haven't specified the return type of `main`, so it defaulted to `int`, and the compiler is warning you about that.

To please the compiler, specify the return type explicitly:

```
int main(void) {
    // code here
}
```

Comment: Adding `void` there is a needless backwards step likely only to confuse the OP.

Comment: Understood, though I do have a follow-up question:  does void work the same way in C++ as it does in Java (in that it does not return anything)?  I appreciate your help and feedback.

Comment: @SteveP., as you can see, the `void` is not the return type here (`int` is). If it were `void main(void)`, that would mean that `main` doesn't return anything (which isn't true since it should return an integer). The `void` in the parentheses (instead of the parameter list) means that the function doesn't accept any arguments.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand now.  I appreciate your further clarification and helping me to understand the code.